# How to url encode user input on a pug form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pug, urlencode

I have inherited a website which involves a heavy amount of pugjs files. Up until this point I had no experience with this technology. Basically, I had a penetration test done and it was determined that this site is vulnerable to http parameter pollution attacks.

I want to URL-encode the user input before it is submitted, but I have no idea based on the technology about how to do that.

I have watched a few tutorials and I am not getting very far. I have trimmed this code down to a manageable chunk.

```
block content
  .body#main
    main
      .row
          if mode === "login"
            .ui.segment
              form.ui.form(action="/login", method="POST")
                .row.form-row
                    label='Username'
                    input(type='text' name='username' placeholder='Your username')
                .row.form-row
                    label='Password'
                    input(type='password' name='password' placeholder='Your password')
                .row.form-row
                    button.ui.fluid.inverted.orange.button(type='submit')='LOG IN'
                .ui.small.error.message
            .ui.small.message
              | Forgot Password or New User?&nbsp;
              a(href='/forgot') Click Here
block append scripts
  script(src='/assets/scripts/login-bundle.js' type='text/javascript')
  if mode === "login" || mode === "forgot"
    script(type="text/javascript").
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').form({
          fields: {
            username: {
              identifier  : 'username',
              rules: [
                {
                  type   : 'empty',
                  prompt : 'Username must not be blank'
                }
              ]
            },
            password: {
              identifier  : 'password',
              rules: [
                {
                  type   : 'empty',
                  prompt : 'Please enter your password'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        });
      });
      });
```

Comment: Isn't an [_"http parameter pollution attack"_](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_(OTG-INPVAL-004)) a problem with how you handle incoming request parameters? I don't think it's got much to do with this front-end code. If anything, I'd say you should look at whatever handles the request for `/login`

Comment: This is a client side and serverside issue. I am fixing the client side vulnerabilities. As per the link you linked.  "To test for HPP client-side vulnerabilities, identify any form or action that allows user input and shows a result of that input back to the user. A search page is ideal, but a login box might not work (as it might not show an invalid username back to the user).


Similarly to server-side HPP, pollute each HTTP parameter with %26HPP_TEST and look for url-decoded occurrences of the user-supplied payload:"